# Multiple samplings and calculating Standard deviation and standard error of the Mean using a trend line

Tags: r, random, sampling

Assuming I have the following data:

```html
df1<-rnorm(100,000, 20,5)
```

I want to get the following samples from df1 with 50 trials each:

```html
C=( 25,50,100,200,300,400,500,600)
```

Next, I want to plot a trend line. In the trend line plot, the x-axis= Sample size and the y-axis
 is **SD** and **SEM**. Sorry, I was unable to draw the plot, but hopefully, my description is clear. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure what you're attempting to do here but this is a first pass at it with what I think you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_theme = theme_minimal() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.title = element_blank())

df1 <- rnorm(100000, 20, 5)

df <- data.frame(sample_size = c(25,50,100,200,300,400,500,600))

samples <- lapply(df$sample_size, function (x) {sample(df1, x)})

df$std <- sapply(samples, sd)
df$se <- sapply(samples, function(x) {sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))})


ggplot(data = df) + geom_point(aes(x = sample_size, y = std, colour = "std")) + geom_point(aes(x = sample_size, y = se, colour = "se")) + 
    geom_smooth(aes(x = sample_size, y = std), method = "lm",) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = sample_size, y = se), method = "lm") + my_theme
```

I prefer to use the ggplot2 library for plots rather than what comes with base R. You can ignore the `my_theme` part, that's just the aesthetic I prefer. Here's the plot:

[image]

If this isn't what you're looking for, you should be able to modify what's here to get what you want, unless I've completely misunderstood your question. In any case, the important part is to use `lapply` and `sample` to get a list of samples from `df1`. Then, you can just calculate the standard deviation of each using `sapply` and `sd` and the standard error using `sapply`, `sd`, `sqrt`, and `length`.

Both `sapply` and `lapply` are useful especially since user defined functions can be passed as arguments in place. I'd recommend looking at [lapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) to understand what it's doing (`sapply` is simply a wrapper to `lapply` that returns a vector).

Comment: Why would the standard deviation increase with sample size? I'm assuming the standard deviation you're looking for is the standard deviation in the individual samples?

Comment: Oh, apologies. Why would it decrease? The standard deviation will change given the samples are different, but will not necessarily decrease. It will, however, approach the standard deviation of the distribution generating the samples (i.e. 5).

Comment: Well, I'm now very unsure what you're looking for. Do you want 50 samples for each size in `C=( 2525,50,100,200,300,400,500,600)`? If that's the case, where does the standard deviation and standard error of the mean fit into that?

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest replacing `df <- data.frame(sample_size = c(25,50,100,200,300,400,500,600)` with `df <- data.frame(sample_size = rep(c(25,50,100,200,300,400,500,600), times = rep(50,8)))`.